# Creating customary Chapter style

Tags: thesis

I am trying to create a customary Chapter style in the following way (made in Word):

[image: Chapter style]

How can I get the following style, with the ability to change the text size?  And does the coding go before or after \begin{document}? Any guidance will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You also want to have the pilcrows??

Comment: Nope. Just giving an indication on the spacing I require. :-)

Comment: Just another question: ‘Introduction’ is the chapter title? I ask this because the 1 is repeated, so I'm unsure whether it's the first chapter title or the first section of the first (untitled) chapter.

Comment: 1st section of the 1st chapter. So Chapter 2 will show "CHAPTER 2" and "1 INTRODUCTION"

Answer (score 1):

Does this layout, obtained with `titlesec`, befit you?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\LARGE\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\kern 1pt·%
\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{4\baselineskip}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Huge}{\arabic{section}}{0.5em}{\uppercase}[\vskip 1.5em\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{4\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to specify earlier, but does it come in Latex font?

Comment: I didn't specify whatever in the preamble, so yes. The  sans font used in title is therefore Computer Modern Sans (cmss). Did you want another font?

Comment: Hey Bernard, thank you for your message. I just want normal Latex font. How would I specify that?

Comment: @HK94 Look at the `|titleformat` code. Any chance that you will notice a "type style" command like `\sffamily`? Either eliminate that or change it to your liking. --- GOM

Comment: @HK94: As Pater wilson mentioned in his comment, just remove `\sffamily` in both `\titleformat`s. Please see if the result of the modified code is OK now.